# What kind of implementation that can get all the SubProjects in each IncludedBuilds in Gradle with the customized tasks?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy

This is the problem: it couldn't found the include project or what we called subprojects, in each includedBuilds or the rootProjects.

```
//build.gradle <root>
def excludedBuilds = ["docker", "internals"]

["clean", "build", "Check"].each { taskName ->
    tasks.create(taskName.concat("All")) {
        group = '<3 in 1>'
        gradle.includedBuilds.each { build ->
            if (excludedBuilds.contains(build.name)) return
            dependsOn gradle.includedBuild(build.name).task(":${???}:$taskName")
//                                                               ^ HERE, how can we get all of the subProjects in each includedBuilds?
        }
    }
}
// figure 1.0
```

And what is the KOTLIN script version of this one(figure 1.0)?

can we turn this (figure 2.0) into (figure 1.0).

```
// figure 2.0
tasks.register("checkAll") {
    group = "<HERE>"
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("application").task(":app:check"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("application").task(":main-frame:check"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("utilities").task(":our-strings:check"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("utilities").task(":our-maths:check"))
}

tasks.register("buildAll") {
    group = "<HERE>"
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("application").task(":app:build"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("application").task(":main-frame:build"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("utilities").task(":our-strings:build"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("utilities").task(":our-maths:build"))
}

tasks.register("cleanAll") {
    group = "<HERE>"
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("application").task(":app:clean"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("application").task(":main-frame:clean"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("utilities").task(":our-strings:clean"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("utilities").task(":our-maths:clean"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one could satisfied my brain? I know it kind of OFF. but yeah, it is working.(painstakingly!)

```
def excludedBuilds = ["<excluded build>", "<and so on>"]
def utilities = ["<subProj#1>", "<subProj#2>", "<and so on>"]
def application = ["<subProj#1>", "<subProj#2>", "<and so on>"]
def arrayz;

["clean", "build", "check"].each { taskName ->
    tasks.create(taskName.concat("All")) {
        group = '<3 in 1>'
        gradle.includedBuilds.each { build ->
            if (excludedBuilds.contains(build.name)) return
            switch(build.name) {
                case "application":
                    arrayz = application
                    break;
                case "utilities":
                    arrayz = utilities
                    break;
                default:
                    return
            }
            for(String subProj : arrayz)
                dependsOn gradle.includedBuild(build.name).task(":$subProj:$taskName")
        }
    }
}
```

We can also try this one.

```
arrayz.each { subProj ->
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild(build.name).task(":$subProj:$taskName")
}
```